# Error building Titanium android module

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I'm having trouble building a brand new canned generated module out of titanium studio on mac os x. I'm able to build fine on linux but when I try on my mac I'm getting some weird errors out of ant build:

```
Buildfile: /Users/michael/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/titanium_rtmp/build.xml

python.set.exec:

python.check:
     [echo] Testing for Python
     [exec] Python 2.7.2

init:

process.annotations:

generate.v8.bindings:
     [java] Generating /Users/michael/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/titanium_rtmp/build/generated/jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.h
     [java] Generating /Users/michael/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/titanium_rtmp/build/generated/jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp
     [java] Generating /Users/michael/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/titanium_rtmp/build/generated/jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.TitaniumRtmpModule.h
     [java] Generating /Users/michael/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/titanium_rtmp/build/generated/jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.TitaniumRtmpModule.cpp

generate.bindings:

pre.compile:

js.compile:

ndk.build:
     [copy] Copying 11 files to /var/folders/_6/6jjydzjs457fnpsc9_5cgl980000gn/T/michael/titaniumRTMP-generated
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:32: warning: overriding commands for target `/private/var/folders/_6/6jjydzjs457fnpsc9_5cgl980000gn/T/michael/titAndroid NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lkroll-v8    
     [exec] Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
     [exec] Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LaniumRTMP-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:32: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/private/var/foldeIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
     [exec] Android NDK:     current module    
     [exec] Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Androirs/_6/6jjydzjs457fnpsc9_5cgl980000gn/T/michael/titaniumRTMP-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:35: warning: ovd.mk:com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lkroll-v8    
     [exec] Android NDK:     This is likely to reerriding commands for target `/private/var/folders/_6/6jjydzjs457fnpsc9_5cgl980000gn/T/michael/titaniumRTMP-generated/BootstrapJsult in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
     [exec] Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the liS.cpp'
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:35: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/private/var/folders/_6/6jjydzjs457fnpsc9_5cgl980000gn/T/mibrary dependencies of the    
     [exec] Android NDK:     current module    
     [exec] Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:com.innoverselabs.titaniumchael/titaniumRTMP-generated/BootstrapJS.cpp'
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:32: warning: overriding commands for target `/private/var/folders/_.rtmp: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lkroll-v8    
     [exec] Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try u6/6jjydzjs457fnpsc9_5cgl980000gn/T/michael/titaniumRTMP-generated/KrollGeneratedBindings.cpp'
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:32: warning: ignorising LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
     [exec] Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
     [exec] Ang old commands for target `/private/var/folders/_6/6jjydzjs457fnpsc9_5cgl980000gn/T/michael/titaniumRTMP-generated/KrollGeneratndroid NDK:     current module    
     [exec] Compile++ thumb  : com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp <= com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleedBindings.cpp'
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:35: warning: overriding commands for target `/private/var/folders/_6/6jjydzjs457fnpsc9_5cgl980000Proxy.cpp
     [exec] gn/T/michael/titaniumRTMP-generated/BootstrapJS.cpp'
     [exec] jni/Android.mk:35: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/private/var/folders/_6/6jjydzjs457fnpsc9_5cgl980000gn/T/michael/titaniumRTMP-generated/BootstrapJS.cpp'
     [exec] In file included from jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:10:0:
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.h:22:1: error: expected class-name before '{' token
     [exec] In file included from jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:12:0:
     [exec] /Users/michael/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/android/native/include/AndroidUtil.h: In destructor 'titanium::LogTimer::~LogTimer()':
     [exec] /Users/michael/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/android/native/include/AndroidUtil.h:57:3: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 5 has type 'long int' [-Wformat]
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp: In constructor 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::rtmp::titaniumrtmp::ExampleProxy::ExampleProxy(jobject)':
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:38:65: error: expected class-name before '(' token
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:38:65: error: expected '{' before '(' token
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp: At global scope:
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:39:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '{' token
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp: In static member function 'static void com::innoverselabs::titanium::rtmp::titaniumrtmp::ExampleProxy::dispose()':
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:63:12: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::TiViewProxy' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp: In static member function 'static v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate> com::innoverselabs::titanium::rtmp::titaniumrtmp::ExampleProxy::getProxyTemplate()':
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:74:24: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JNIUtil' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:80:41: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::Proxy' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:81:13: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::TiViewProxy' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:85:31: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::Proxy' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:86:35: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::Proxy' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:86:62: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:86:63: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:88:12: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::ProxyFactory' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:99:56: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::Proxy' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:100:13: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::Proxy' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp: In static member function 'static v8::Handle<v8::Value> com::innoverselabs::titanium::rtmp::titaniumrtmp::ExampleProxy::setMessage(const v8::Arguments&)':
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:121:26: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JNIScope' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:123:20: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JSException' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:130:4: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:131:22: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JSException' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:135:2: error: 'Proxy' is not a member of 'com::innoverselabs::titanium'
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:135:2: note: suggested alternative:
     [exec] /Users/michael/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/android/native/include/Proxy.h:17:7: note:   'titanium::Proxy'
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:135:19: error: 'proxy' was not declared in this scope
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:135:37: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::Proxy' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:153:14: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::TypeConverter' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:161:7: error: 'JavaObject' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:171:13: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JSException' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp: In static member function 'static v8::Handle<v8::Value> com::innoverselabs::titanium::rtmp::titaniumrtmp::ExampleProxy::getMessage(const v8::Arguments&)':
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:186:26: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JNIScope' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:188:20: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JSException' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:195:4: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:196:22: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JSException' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:200:2: error: 'Proxy' is not a member of 'com::innoverselabs::titanium'
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:200:2: note: suggested alternative:
     [exec] /Users/michael/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/android/native/include/Proxy.h:17:7: note:   'titanium::Proxy'
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:200:19: error: 'proxy' was not declared in this scope
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:200:37: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::Proxy' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:209:7: error: 'JavaObject' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:216:41: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JSException' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:225:37: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::TypeConverter' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp: In static member function 'static v8::Handle<v8::Value> com::innoverselabs::titanium::rtmp::titaniumrtmp::ExampleProxy::printMessage(const v8::Arguments&)':
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:238:26: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JNIScope' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:240:20: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JSException' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:247:4: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:248:22: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JSException' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:252:2: error: 'Proxy' is not a member of 'com::innoverselabs::titanium'
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:252:2: note: suggested alternative:
     [exec] /Users/michael/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/android/native/include/Proxy.h:17:7: note:   'titanium::Proxy'
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:252:19: error: 'proxy' was not declared in this scope
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:252:37: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::Proxy' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:270:14: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::TypeConverter' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:278:7: error: 'JavaObject' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:288:13: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JSException' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp: In static member function 'static v8::Handle<v8::Value> com::innoverselabs::titanium::rtmp::titaniumrtmp::ExampleProxy::getter_message(v8::Local<v8::String>, const v8::AccessorInfo&)':
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:306:26: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JNIScope' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:308:20: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JSException' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:315:4: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:316:22: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JSException' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:320:2: error: 'Proxy' is not a member of 'com::innoverselabs::titanium'
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:320:2: note: suggested alternative:
     [exec] /Users/michael/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/android/native/include/Proxy.h:17:7: note:   'titanium::Proxy'
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:320:19: error: 'proxy' was not declared in this scope
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:320:37: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::Proxy' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:333:7: error: 'JavaObject' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:340:41: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JSException' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:349:37: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::TypeConverter' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp: In static member function 'static void com::innoverselabs::titanium::rtmp::titaniumrtmp::ExampleProxy::setter_message(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const v8::AccessorInfo&)':
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:363:26: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JNIScope' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:374:4: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:378:2: error: 'Proxy' is not a member of 'com::innoverselabs::titanium'
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:378:2: note: suggested alternative:
     [exec] /Users/michael/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/android/native/include/Proxy.h:17:7: note:   'titanium::Proxy'
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:378:19: error: 'proxy' was not declared in this scope
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:378:37: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::Proxy' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:390:14: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::TypeConverter' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:398:7: error: 'JavaObject' has not been declared
     [exec] jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.cpp:408:13: error: 'com::innoverselabs::titanium::JSException' has not been declared
     [exec] cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
     [exec] 
     [exec] make: *** [/var/folders/_6/6jjydzjs457fnpsc9_5cgl980000gn/T//michael/titaniumRTMP-generated/obj/local/armeabi/objs/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.o] Error 1

BUILD FAILED
/Users/michael/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/module/android/build.xml:326: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/michael/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA/module/android/build.xml:281: exec returned: 2

Total time: 2 seconds
```

I have everything set correctly (including NDK path in my build.properties. I've also tried re-downloading the NDK and tried the 32bit and 64bit mac version and consistently get the same error. I also tried moving my titanium platform to a location without spaces and still received the same error.

Comment: can you post the project/source somewhere since it appears to be a syntax error in some code. jni/com.innoverselabs.titanium.rtmp.ExampleProxy.h:22:1: error: expected class-name before '{' token

Comment: That's what I thought, but I'm using the auto generated code from titanium. I will post the proxy code but it's the directly generated titamium create .... code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the ExampleProxy Class was the only thing that eventually solved for me. Subsequent modules made with the ExampleProxy DID work however after an SDK upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have xCode on your mac machine?

Open xCode and install the Command Line Tools - I think that should do it.

Comment: Yes I do and this was one of the first things I did.

Comment: OK. It's a good thing to verify that it is installed. Here's a funny one - I just wanted to recompile an old module of mine and got the same error (on a machine that the module was originally build with). I check and I had command line tools installed. After doing some trail error testing what I found was that the NDK version I had on my machine (newest one) was not compatible with the SDK version that I was compiling against (2.1.4.GA). So I downloaded and referenced an older version of NDK (r8b). So you could also check if your NDK and Titanium SDK versions match.

Comment: I just had it again when I started testing the new platform. Read my about what I found out here: http://developer82.webe.co.il/appcelerator/appcelerator-titanium-android-native-module-exec-returned-2/ and here: http://developer82.webe.co.il/appcelerator/more-on-exec-returned-2/